# How to execute a NestJs TCP Microservice command by nodeJs

Tags: node.js, tcp, microservices, nestjs

I have a working Microservice(MS) based on https://docs.nestjs.com/microservices/basics using a TCP protocol. Executing a command from my NestJS API was easy by implementing the `@nestjs/microservices` Client.

Now im working on a Lambda (AWS) in plain **nodeJs**, this lambda contains a function that also need to send a command to the MS. I tried using `net` to create a Socket to send a command (stringified) but it doesn't trigger anything.
my example nodeJs code:

```
const net = require('net');
const saveProducts = (products) => {
  let socket = new net.Socket();
  socket.setEncoding('UTF8');
  socket.on('data', function (data) {
    console.log('ON DATA'); // print out data
    console.log(data.toString()); // print out data
  });

  socket.connect(options.port, options.host, function () {
    //called when connection is created
    const command = JSON.stringify({ pattern: { cmd: 'update-many', ctrl: 'product' } });
    socket.write(command, 'UTF8', function (err) {
      console.log(err);
    });
  });
}
```

I have used a network sniffer to get an example message structure..

[similar issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55942795/call-my-nestjs-microservice-with-nodejs-app) but the suggestion is only to add `@nestjs/microservices`, I was wondering how to do it without it.

Answer (score 1):

After some long research found out what the pattern is what you need to send:

`[MSG_LEN]#{ pattern: "[PATTERN_STRING]", data: "[DATA]", id: "[ID]" }`

Example:

`62#{"pattern":"find","id":"ce51ebd3-32b1-4ae6-b7ef-e018126c4cc4"}`

The parameter `id` is for `@MessagePattern`, without it `@EventPattern` will be triggered.